# Target another styled component on hover not working

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I need help with hover in  styled components. If hover is in component and affect that component, that work. But if hover is in component and affect another component, not working.

DropDownContent not show on DropDownLi:hover.

```
export const DropDownLi = styled(StyledLi)`
  display: inline-block;

  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
`;

export const DropDownContent = styled.div`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;

  ${DropDownLi}:hover & {
    display: block;
  } 
  /* not show on hover */
`;
```

Not working in next example.

```
export const DropDownLi = styled(StyledLi)`
  display: inline-block;

  &:hover ${DropDownContent} {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

```
<StyledUl>
  <DropDownLi>$ Currency</DropDownLi> 
  <DropDownContent>dvsdv</DropDownContent>
  <DropDownLi>English</DropDownLi>
  <StyledLi>Login</StyledLi>
</StyledUl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `&`:

```
export const DropDownContent = styled.div`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;

  ${DropDownLi}:hover {
    display: block;
  } 
  /* not show on hover */
`;
```

Comment: Thank you @Georgy for help, but it is not working without `&`.

Comment: ah I see, you want to show parent component if you hover on child component, right? I'm not sure you could do it using CSS. Cascading works from top levels to bottom.

Comment: I updated question, so you can see. I want to show child component (`DropDownContent`) on hover another child component (`DropDownLi`). I need dropdown with styled-components. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. The code that works is below.

```
<StyledUl>
  <DropDownLi>
    $ Currency
    <DropDownContent>dvsdv</DropDownContent>
  </DropDownLi>
</StyledUl>
```

```
export const StyledLi = styled.li`
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const DropDownContent = styled.div`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
`;
export const DropDownLi = styled(StyledLi)`
  display: inline-block;
`;

export const StyledUl = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;

  ${DropDownLi}:hover > ${DropDownContent} {
    display: block;
  }
`;
```